# What is the default sort order of zfs list, and is there a locale taken into account with zfs list -s creation?

Tags: zfs, snapshot

I would like to get a list of snapshots, *ordered by creation time*, for an arbitrary rpool.

My first problem is that I can't find out which is the default sort order of `zfs list -t snapshot`. `zfs`'s man page states (excerpt):

```
zfs list [-r|-d depth] [-Hp] [-o property[,property]...] [-s property]... [-S property]... [-t type[,type]...] [filesystem|volume|snapshot]...

       [...]
   
       -s property
           A property for sorting the output by column in ascending order based on the value of the property.  The property must be one of the properties
           described in the Properties section, or the special value name to sort by the dataset name.  Multiple properties can be specified at one time
           using multiple -s property options.  Multiple -s options are evaluated from left to right in decreasing order of importance.  The following is
           a list of sorting criteria:

           •   Numeric types sort in numeric order.

           •   String types sort in alphabetical order.

           •   Types inappropriate for a row sort that row to the literal bottom, regardless of the specified ordering.

           If no sorting options are specified the existing behavior of zfs list is preserved.

       [...]
```

There is no hint about the default sorting order. The last sentence of the section shown above does not help because I don't know what `the existing order of zfs list` means.

I strongly suppose that the default order is by creation time, but I would like to have this confirmed, and I would be grateful if somebody could give a reference.

I am aware that I can let zfs order the list by creation time by giving the appropriate parameters explicitly, i.e. by issuing a command like that:

```
zfs list -t snapshot -s creation
```

However, this leads to the next problem. I could not a find a reference about how ZFS actually stores the creation time. I am actually sure that it generates those timestamps from the epoch time or from UTC time, instead of using local time; otherwise, we would run into all sorts of problems with DST and similar oddities, wouldn't we? Although I am sure, I would be grateful (again) if somebody could shed some light on this.

Comment: No reference, but listing my snaps by creation time and then by default order both appear identical so I think your assumption about default order has merit. I'm not sure what you are actually asking since you've stated that you do know how to list them by creation time?

Comment: *I'm not sure what you are actually asking* Perhaps I am too paranoid, but to give an example: If it would take the *local* time as creation time, we would probably have quite a mess. And if we go totally crazy, we could understand the term "order by creation time" as "order by the creation time as it is represented by a string in the respective locale". Both would be totally silly, and I'm confident (and have tested in the meanwhile) that zfs does the right thing. However, I'd feel more comfortable if somebody would confirm that there are no pitfalls.

Comment: Have you tried comparing `zfs list -rt all -o name,creation <pool>/<dataset>` to the `ls -lU` listing of the `<dataset mountpoint>/.zfs/snapshot` directory? `ls -U` sorts by creation time.